# VS2010 doesn't have 'copy' option on right click menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

When I make a selection and try to copy something from VS2010 help (F1), it doesn't give me 'copy' option. This is really annoying. Anyone one know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: @aquinas That apparently works but it's still annoying.

Comment: FWIW, the Help Viewer 2.0 in VS2012 fixes this.